# How can I arrange a set of varying line segments to form a polygon that is circumscribed by a circle?

Tags: geometry, programming

This is for a small web library I'm working on, presenting images as a 3D carousel rotating around a y-axis. [Here's a quick demo of what I have](https://jsfiddle.net/jacob_ewing/xoLdh82j/10/).

Unfortunately, that's not quite what I want.  If they're all the same size it works fine, but if any of them are inconsistent (which will usually be the case), then they protrude or recede depending on their relative size.

I don't know if the problem is in my math or my implementation of it, so I'm hoping someone can either explain where I went wrong or suggest a better method.

Here's how I worked out the radius at which they're displayed.  I'm also not 100% sure if I correctly calculated the required angle (theta):
[image: chart]

Any correction/suggestion would be duly appreciated!

Comment: https://chaosinmotion.com/2016/10/02/constructing-a-cyclic-polygon-given-the-edge-lengths/

Answer (score 1):

If $2\theta_k$ is the central angle insisting on side $L_k$, and $r$ is the radius of the circle, the equations to solve are:
$$
{1\over2r}={\sin\theta_1\over L_1}={\sin\theta_2\over L_2}=
\dots={\sin\theta_{n-1}\over L_{n-1}}=
{\sin(\theta_1+\theta_2+\dots+\theta_{n-1})\over L_n}.
$$
And this system of equations should be solved by some numerical method.

Answer (score 0):

Too long for a comment, but…

You won’t be able to have **both** the same perpendicular distance from the centre of the circle to each image (of varying widths) **and** have all the images on the edges of a concyclic polygon.

Instead you could consider arranging it so that all the varying polygon edges are tangent to an inscribed circle.

Comment: I'm not actually looking for them to have the same distance from centre.  I want to be able to align them so that the images are all chords of the same circle and connected end-to-end.  I'm not concerned about the circle's radius.